# Unable to rename file in tmp folder in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have changed the permissions of `tmp` folder to `0777` but still Symfony is throwing a permission error :

```
rename(\/tmp\/__CG__MyEntity.php.55eab1cb8bee30.16966444,\/tmp\/__CG__MyEntity.php), operation not permitted.
```

Comment: This question depends of PHP. Not Symfony.

Comment: As of PHP, i have already changed the permissions but it still doesn't work. I was asking for any solution related to Symfony.

Comment: Hi @Ritesh. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @shadi nopes. Nothing worked.